# Подскажите,в чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("lst");
  var myList_first = myList.firstChild.innerHTML;
  var myList_last = myList.lastChild.innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = '<b>Первый элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_first + '<br>' + '<b>Последний элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_last;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="lst">
    <li id="li1">Кофе</li>
    <li id="li2">Чай</li>
    <li id="li3">Какао</li>
    <li id="li4">Молоко</li>
    <li id="li5">Сок</li>
  </ol>

  <button onClick="myFunction()">
Поиск первого и последнего элемента списка
</button>

  <p id="res"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Подскажите, в чём вопрос ?

Comment: Почему при выполнении кода появляется undefined? Должно по идее выдавать Кофе как первый элемент и Сок как последний.

Comment: потому что у вас функция вызывается раньше чем определяется

Comment: @humster_spb ответ неверный, это ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal, я скопировал код в песочницу и в отладчике увидел ошибку: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @humster_spb значит скопировали криво, сниппет работает нормально (не считая описанной автором проблемы)

Comment: @andreymal, я нормально скопировал: https://jsfiddle.net/ox7qavbm/5/

Comment: @humster_spb jsfiddle заворачивает код в замыкание, поэтому и не работает. Говорю же — криво скопировали :) Вам религия не позволяет нажать кнопочку «Выполнить код» прямо на сайте Stack Overflow?

Comment: @andreymal, и что мне даст "выполнить код" здесь? модифицировать его здесь нельзя - для этого и нужна песочница, чтобы разобраться

Comment: @humster_spb если здесь код работает, а в вашей песочнице не работает, то при чём тут код?)

Comment: @humster_spb раз вы так любите jsfiddle, то https://jsfiddle.net/4dbvess7/

Comment: @andreymal, если код не воспроизводится в песочнице, он плохой: вызывать onclick прямо в html-разметке - это очень дурной тон

Comment: @humster_spb смотрите мою ссылку, всё воспроизводится

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `firstElementChild` и `lastElementChild`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("lst");
  var myList_first = myList.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
  var myList_last = myList.lastElementChild.innerHTML;
  

  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = '<b>Первый элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_first + '<br>' + '<b>Последний элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_last;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="lst">
    <li id="li1">Кофе</li>
    <li id="li2">Чай</li>
    <li id="li3">Какао</li>
    <li id="li4">Молоко</li>
    <li id="li5">Сок</li>
  </ol>

  <button onClick="myFunction()">
Поиск первого и последнего элемента списка
</button>

  <p id="res"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле DOM внутри элемента `ol` устроен так:

1. Строка с переносом строки и четырьмя пробелами
2. Элемент li1
3. Строка с переносом строки и четырьмя пробелами
4. Элемент li2
5. Строка с переносом строки и четырьмя пробелами
6. Элемент li3
7. Строка с переносом строки и четырьмя пробелами
8. Элемент li4
9. Строка с переносом строки и четырьмя пробелами
10. Элемент li5
11. Строка с переносом строки и двумя пробелами

`firstChild` и `lastChild` ссылаются на первого и последнего потомка соответственно независимо от типа — и в вашем случае это оказываются строки (пункты 1 и 11).

Вам следует использовать вместо них `firstElementChild` и `lastElementChild` — они пропускают строки и берут именно элементы (пункты 2 и 10).

Не пытайтесь решить проблему стиранием всех пробелов и переносов строк: некоторые браузеры просто оставят в DOM пустые строки вместо них.

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myList = document.getElementById("lst").children;

    var myList_first = myList[0].innerHTML;
    var myList_last = myList[myList.length - 1].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = '<b>Первый элемент в списке: </b>' + myList_first + '<br>' + '<b>Последний элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_last;
}
```

Comment: Суть задания-использование методов firstChild и lastChild

Comment: @HarukiMurakami этого не было в вашем вопросе:)

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, как вариант решения:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("lst");
  var myList_first = myList.firstChild.innerHTML;
  var myList_last = myList.lastChild.innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = '<b>Первый элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_first + '<br>' + '<b>Последний элемент в списке:</b>' + myList_last;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="lst"
    ><li id="li1">Кофе</li
    ><li id="li2">Чай</li
    ><li id="li3">Какао</li
    ><li id="li4">Молоко</li
    ><li id="li5">Сок</li
  ></ol>

  <button onClick="myFunction()">
Поиск первого и последнего элемента списка
</button>

  <p id="res"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Я перенес закрывающую угловую скобку на новую строку.
Причина того, почему у вас это не работает:
т.к. нет переноса, появляется пробел между `li`-блоками на каждой строке. Поэтому первый и последний чайлд - `#text Node` (подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)). 
Перенос скобочек таким образом позволяет избежать появления этих пробелов (или можно просто все записать в одну строку).

**Однако** вариант с использованием `firstElementChild` является лучшим решением, ибо я не гарантирую работоспособность этого фикса в разных браузерах.

Comment: Забавно, что я в соседнем ответе написал не делать этого :)

Comment: @andreymal хах. Да, я согласен, что `firstElementChild` будет более правильным решением, но все же счел нужным описать проблему, и вышло так...) Просто добавлю, что `firstElementChild` предпочтительнее.

Comment: Впрочем, я чего-то сейчас сходу не могу найти браузеры, в которых это не работало бы; возможно, моя информация устарела

Comment: @andreymal я не особо прошарен в теме web, но часто встречал такой путь решения для данной проблемы, предлагаемый экспертами SO) и поэтому утверждать не буду) кстати, хтмл же часто парсится с одной строки, прям как json, так что мб это все же общепринятая практика в разных браузерах, ибо было бы совсем не очень...